# task manager private working set lower than performance monitor private bytes

Tags: windows-server-2012, task-manager, performance-monitor

I'm trying to track a memory leak in an application, so I had performance monitor  graph its private bytes. One time, performance monitor said that the private bytes was rising, but in task manager, the private working set remained the same and lower than the number of private bytes.

I understand if the task manager's private working set is higher than performance monitor's  private bytes since I know the private working set includes shared memory. But does it mean anything special if the private working set is lower than the private bytes?

Comment: Private working set DOES NOT include shared objects unless the process itself created them. Private WS should always be lower than or equal to Private Bytes on a process by process basis. To directly answer your question, when Private WS is less than Private Bytes, that should indicate that a portion of the process has been paged out to disk.

Comment: use ETW to trace memory leak: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks

Answer (score 3):

Private working set is physical memory (RAM), Private Bytes is virtual.  (It's called "private committed" in some places.) Private working set is the paged-in, or "resident", subset of Private Bytes. So this is entirely expected behavior.

Note that the difference is not necessarily "paged out to disk". Private memory that's been committed but not yet referenced occupies *neither* RAM nor disk file space.

This is easy to verify with the sysinternals testlimit tool. With the -m option it commits private virtual address space, but doesn't reference it, so the allocation shows up in "private bytes" but not at all in the working set OR in pagefile space used. With the -d option is commits but also "touches" (writes to) the virtual memory, which causes it to be "faulted in", and only then does the OS allocate RAM for it.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted explain why? Maybe provide a reference for countering information?